# How do I install Intel drivers?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, intel-graphics, desktop-environments, ubuntu-gnome

I installed my Ubuntu with my GTX 980 on board, but I want to sell it and use my HD 4600 that I have with my i7.

Will it be enough to run the gnome desktop smoothly and how can I do that?

Comment: I see no problems to use the integrated Intel adapter. You do not need drivers for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have 16.04 (and then 16.10, 17.04, etc when they come out), you don't need to install anything for Intel. The drivers are either open source or Intel allows Ubuntu to include them in the installation. Most of the time, Intel works OOTB.

As for performance, well that's a little more complicated. 4600 should be enough for GNOME (and even KDE), normal web browsing, videos and a few low-power games. It won't be nearly as great as the 980 in terms of performance, but if you aren't a serious gamer, you'll get along fine with Intel.

If you do game, do not sell the card. Intel graphics are great for work, but not so much for play. Minecraft will be fine on Intel (not great, but OK), but something like Deus Ex might not be so nice.

Maybe you do something in between: some low-power games and work. In that case, buy a lower performance NVIDIA card (DO NOT get AMD) and sell the 980.

Comment: Forgot to include that im running 3 1080p displays.
I do not do any kind of gaming, I sometimes play civilization, but it runs fine on my intel graphics.
I do programming, blender and of course i watch videos on my computer, thats about it.

I will look in to something like a gt 740. I feel like that would be nice.

Comment: @tomkis you should probably just take the card out and try to use the computer normally. See how it turns out.

Answer (score 1):

Unity (based on Gnome desktop) and reportedly more resource intensive runs great on my 2012 Dell Laptop (Intel i7 3630QM) using Intel HD4000.

Unitty also worked fine on my 2007 Toshiba laptop (Core 2 Duo) HD2000.

With 10 chrome tabs open on Dell laptop screen and watching youtube on TV the 8 CPUs are averaging 18% load with the HD4000. Similarly the older Toshiba 4 CPUs used to run at 50% load I believe.

Both laptops automatically use Intel's i915 driver in Linux with no manual installation required. This is true for Ubuntu versions 14.04 and 16.04.

Indeed the Dell Motherboard has a Nvidia GT650M installed that I never even turned on in the two years I've owned it.

PS: Ubuntu 16.04 comes with Kernel 4.4. Due to suspend/resume issues I immediately updated to Kernel 4.6.3. A week later I updated to kernel 4.7.2 and I noticed 8 CPU load balancing was more even and overall load percentage dropped noticeably (let's say from 25% to 18%). Bear in mind these numbers are subjective.

Comment: I never had luck with upgrading my kernel, no matter what I install my system doesnt work anymore

Comment: @tomkis Perhaps you should post an error message you got last time you tried to upgrade kernel?

Comment: I get something about Sysinit,then a black screen and it shows loading with glitchy graphics,after that best I got was a the ALT + CTRL + F1 terminal, and the terminal would "Restart". so there was no way to boot.

Comment: Probably because of Nvidia drivers. I'm lucky I've always had them turned off and kernel upgrading has been error free.

Comment: ah yes you might be right. Should i try to just reinstall them after upgrading my kernel? and is it even worth to upgrade it?

Comment: @tomkis after you yank your GTX 980 out Nvidia drivers become a mute point. That's when I'd update the kernel to improve performance on the HD4600 if you feel it's necessary.